# Array of an object of a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am trying to write a C++ code that creates and uses an array of object of a class. my question is how do i create an array of an object of a class and how to i declare it in the main

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: What kind of help do you seek? Note: SO is **not** a code writing service.

Comment: How do i create an arrayof an object of class ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It depends on how your class looks but this would be a simple example:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class MyClass { 

 int x; 
 public: 
 void setX(int i) { x = i; } 
 int getX() { return x; } 
 }; 

int main()
{ 
 MyClass test[4]; 
 int i; 
 for(i=0; i < 4; i++) 
   test[i].setX(i); `

 for(i=0; i < 4; i++) 
   cout << "test[" << i << "].getX(): " << test[i].getX() << "\n";`

return 0;
}`
```

Testing it by calling X delivers:

`test[0].getX(): 0
 test[1].getX(): 1
 test[2].getX(): 2
 test[3].getX(): 3`

Comment: That's definitely not an answer.

Comment: he edited the question -  i was referring to the previous version but i´ll edit this answer too (because not theres something to actually answer)

Comment: "because not theres something to actually answer" Exactly.

Comment: *now

Was a typo :b